# Android get edittext is activated

Tags: android

I have three edittext. In first and second i get data from user with keyboard. In third edittext i open DatePickerDialog , get data from it and show edittext.

Here is my question. While user skip to other edittext with keyboard next button , how can i understand that third edittext is activated ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: need more clarification.what do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: You want to do something when the view is focused or view lost focus?

Comment: I want to popup datepickerdialog with keyboard next button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use onfocus changelistenerlike this:

```
name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.liganame);
name.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
email.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);

date = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
date.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
```

and check the id of your datepicker edittext in onfocuschange like this:

```
 @Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    if(v.getId() == R.id.date && hasFocus){

     //your code here....

     }
}
```